# The series $\sum \frac{1}{p_iq_i}$ where $p_i,q_i$ are twin primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, twin-primes

I am interested in the series comprising the inverses of the products of twin prime pairs: $$\sum_i \frac{1}{p_iq_i}$$ where $p_i=6i-1,\ q_i=6i+1;\ (p_i,q_i) \in \mathbb P$. This series is equivalent to $$\sum_k \left(\frac{1}{36k^2-1}\right)$$ for $k \in$ [OEIS 002822](https://oeis.org/A002822). The term $\frac{1}{3\cdot 5}$ for the twin prime pair that does not have the desired form is omitted from the series as I consider it, but it can readily added to the result if doing so would be in any way enlightening.

Computationally, the first forty terms sum to $0.0412994859\dots$ In this range, the final terms are $\approx 10^{-6}$

The series converges. I offer two proofs. **First:** $$p_i^2<p_i\cdot p_{i+1} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{p_i^2}>\frac{1}{p_i\cdot p_{i+1}} \Rightarrow \sum_i \left(\frac{1}{p_i^2}\right) > \sum_i \left(\frac{1}{p_i\cdot p_{i+1}}\right)$$ But $\sum_i \left(\frac{1}{p_i^2}\right)=P(2)$ where $P(2)$ is the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function), which converges. So the sum of the inverse of the products of *all* pairs of sequential primes must converge, and the series that I am interested in is a subseries thereof, and hence also converges.

**Second:** The sum of the inverses of the primes which occur in twin primes converges to [Brun's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem). But for each twin prime pair, the sum of the inverses $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p+2}=\frac{2p+2}{p(p+2)}$ is much larger than the inverse of the product itself $\frac{1}{p(p+2)}$. Hence the series I am interested in must converge.

Despite much thought and some searching, I have not been able to find relevant literature or progress beyond this point.

**My questions are:** (1) Has my series been examined previously, and if so, where might I locate those studies? (2) Can anyone provide me with some methods or insights as to how to evaluate the series $\sum_i \frac{1}{p_iq_i}$?

Comment: This is referred to in OEIS sequence [A209328](https://oeis.org/A209328). For future reference, try directly computing and searching some integer terms of your sequence that are as far transformed as possible under your computations of interest, i.e. in this case, searching for the sequence $3\times5,5\times7,\ldots$ directly. And then, look through the links on the OEIS page. I don't think there's all that much known that's interesting to say about it.

Comment: The second proof of convergence does not look rigorous.

Comment: @Kenta S In determining Brun's constant, each twin prime pair contributes two terms to the series. But those two terms can be combined into a single term as I showed. Thus the terms in the (reformulated) Brun's constant series can be matched one to one with the terms in my series. Each term in the (reformulated) Brun's series is much larger than the corresponding term in my series. The terms in both series are all positive and monotonically decreasing. What is not rigorous in concluding that the fact Brun's series converges implies my series converges?

Comment: @KeithBackman you're right, I thought you were somehow using the fact that the terms were "much" larger, whatever that means. It seems you are only using that the terms are larger.